# Getting a global_error_asset_load_failed on Hearthstone in Wine, running Ubuntu

Tags: hearthstone, ubuntu, wine

So I'm getting the error in the title of the question when I try to start Hearthstone in Wine. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
I've only found one thing online, and that's on the battle.net forums [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/16951955405)
and I've already done all the tips suggested so I'm not sure where to go from this point.

I've never really used Wine so I'm not sure where to start looking for any kind of answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to wine > libraries and you must have:

- *dbghelp(native, internal)
- *msvcp100(native, internal)

If not, just write the name and click add.
I had this error because i had dbghelp disabled.